# Runnable and Animation stopping Android Studio JUnit Tests

Tags: android, junit, android-animation, runnable

I have multiple JUnit tests that click a button that triggers these functions:

```
public void startTimer() {
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    handler.post(runTimer);
    blink();
}

Runnable runTimer = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run () {

       millisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
       updateTime = bufTime + millisecondTime;
       Seconds = (int) (updateTime / 1000);
       Minutes = (int) (updateTime / 60000);
       Hours = Minutes / 60;
       Minutes = Minutes % 60;
       Seconds = Seconds % 60;
       MilliSeconds = (int) (updateTime % 1000);
       timer.setText(String.format("%02d", Hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", Minutes) + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", Seconds));

       handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}

public void blink() {
     Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
     anim.setDuration(250); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
     anim.setStartOffset(0);
     anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
     anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);    
     redCircle.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

For context, the next step on my JUnit test clicks the button that calls stopping the animation and handler.removeCallbacks(runTimer). However it doesn't even get there because it's just stuck!

When I comment out BOTH the handler.post() and blink() in the startTimer() function, the JUnit tests start working again. I can't seem to find any solutions to this. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this!

I made multiple changes I think this was the main one:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
```

to

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

Also not sure if it helped but in case I also did this:

```
handler.post(runTimer);
```

to

```
runOnUiThread(runTimer);
```